# For-Each Loop On A Layout's Child Views

Tags: java, android, android-layout, foreach, android-view

**Suppposed** that I have a `layout` (like a `Relativelayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc.) with a ton lot of `Views`.

- The case here is that I want to do the very same thing to all of them using a `for-each` method.
- The problem is, you can only `iterate` using the `for-each` method when it qualifies as an `array`.

---

P.S. I know that you can do it like this:

```java
for(int i=0;i<layout.getChildCount();i++){
  final View v=layout.getChildAt(i);
  v.doSomething(parameters);
}
```

- I just have to know if there's another way using the `for-each` method so that I can save time rather than typing that again and again on every app that I develop.

Comment: Looks like your question is about reducing code. You probably don't want to switch to Kotlin, but there you could do something like `(view as? ViewGroup)?.children?.forEach { it.doSomething(parameters) }`. Java also has streams/lambdas as of N. See: https://academy.realm.io/posts/mobilization-eric-kok-functional-android-lambdas-rx-streams-app/.

Comment: @Michael Good guess, I do don't want to switch to Kotlin, I'll look into that link.(Reading as of now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a helper method like:

```
public final class ViewGroupHelper {

    public static void forEach(@NonNull ViewGroup group,
                               @NonNull Action action) {
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            final View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            action.apply(view);
        }
    }

    public interface Action {
        void apply(@NonNull View view);
    }

    private ViewGroupHelper() {}
}
```

...

```
ViewGroupHelper.forEach(layout, new ViewGroupHelper.Action() {
    @Override
    public void apply(@NonNull View view) {
        view.doSomething();
    }
});
```

or with lambda `ViewGroupHelper.forEach(layout, view -> view.doSomething());`

Comment: I like the idea by a lot, could be used on all the class files I have here, could cut of a lot of lines of code, and it's not layout specific nor widget specific. Thanks!